# Cannot assign value of type 'SDWebImageActivityIndicator' to type 'ST_SDWebImageIndicator?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sdwebimage

[image]I have multiple flavours targets in my Xcode project. I am also using `SDWebImage` in my app. Everything was working fine until now. I have upgraded `SDWebImage` to `5.12.3` from `5.10.0`. And now I am getting an error saying that `Cannot assign value of type 'SDWebImageActivityIndicator' to type 'ST_SDWebImageIndicator?’`.
There is nothing in my whole Xcode project named `ST_SDWebImageIndicator`. Weird thing is that some flavours are running perfectly fine and some are giving this error. I have already tried deleting, deintegrating pods and then re installing them but nothing worked so far. Line on which I am getting an error-

```
myImageView.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.gray
```

Some important points-

- This error only occurred in some of the flavours and not all. Some of them run totally fine.
- This error only occurring in this project only. If I install same pods in another projects it works fine.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think it's a typo you may mean `.sd_` not `.st_`

Comment: @Sh_Khan No it's not a typo it's name is sd_imageIndicator. and it's totally working fine for some of my app flavours.

Comment: FYI, cause of error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71035673/identical-property-name-issue-in-different-third-party-dependencies-extensions