# Identical property name issue in different third party dependencies extensions

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have two pods in my project **Pod A** and **Pod B**. Both pods have **UIView** extensions and in both extensions there is a property with same name but the type of those property is different.

**UIView extension in Pod A:**

```
extension UIView {
    var sd_ImageIndicator: SDWebImageIndicator?
}
```

**UIView extension in Pod B:**

```
extension UIView {
    var sd_ImageIndicator: ST_SDWebImageIndicator?
}
```

Now **Pod B** is saving it’s data in **XCFrameworkIntermediates** in derived data. And when I try to access the property **sd_ImageIndicator** of **Pod A** on a view from a class in my app, it picks the property of **Pod B** from **XCFrameworkIntermediates**. What I want is that it should pick that property from **Pod A** instead of **XCFrameworkIntermediates** derived data of **Pod B**.

One other case - I have different targets in my project and it’s not occurring for all of them. Some of the targets are having this issue.
I have already tried pod deintegrate, deleting pods, derived data and re installing pods, running app on different Mac but nothing has worked so far.

Another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71020126/cannot-assign-value-of-type-sdwebimageactivityindicator-to-type-st-sdwebimage) I have posted yesterday related to this issue, in that you can check the error I am getting exactly.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: They both seem to use SDWebImage as a sub dependency. They aren't declaring it? And seeing PodB, they "renamed" the SDWebImage lib properties with a Prefix. That's a design which is quite strange... Do you have control over PodA and PodB? Who made them?

Comment: @Larme , This is the issue, I don't have control over them. And you're right PodB is using SDWebImage as a sub dependency. Earlier PodB used to have separate dependency of SDWebImage which means it automatically install SDWebImage. But now in their recent release they have removed SDWebImage dependency. It seems they just Renamed the SDWebImage properties as you've mentioned in comments. So that's causing the issue now.

Comment: Tell them about the issue then. If they want to do it in a dirty way, they also have to rename `sd_...` into `st_sd...` or `st_`. They are bypassing the (sub)dependency system. I guess that without even `PodA`, if you have just in your project `SDWebImage` & `PodB` same issue will arise. If possible revert to previous version until solution is done.

Comment: @Larme . No, I have tried installing SDWebImage and PodB in another demo project then issue doesn't arise and also I have multiple targets in my project and this issue only occurring for some of the targets and not all.